# Express Jade Layout Won't Render Even Though Layouts Is Set to True

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I am new to Express for Node.js, and I was just setting up a simple app by following [Pedro Teixeira's Node Tuts Episode 9](http://vimeo.com/16892503). I wanted to experiment with layout files, so I set the layout to be "true." When I did that though, it didn't render with my layout, only with my body. How should I get it to render correctly? Below is my app.js file, my index.jade, my layout.jade, and a screenshot of my rendered page.

app.js

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express.createServer();

app.configure(function () {
    app.use(express.logger();
});

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine','jade');
app.set('view options', {layout: true});

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    response.render('index');
});

app.listen(4000);
```

index.jade

```
h2 Hello
p World!
```

layout.jade

```
!!! 5
  html
    head
      title My template
    body
  #main
        h1 Content goes here
        p Testing 123
        #container!= body
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Express 3 this is normal the way template are rendered has changed.

Your layout needs to be like this:

```
!!! 5
  html
    head
      title My template
    body
  #main
        h1 Content goes here
        p Testing 123
        block content
```

And you templates:

```
extends layout

block content
  h1 Something
```

Examples here:

https://github.com/dotcloud/express-on-dotcloud/blob/master/app/views/layout.jade#L64

https://github.com/dotcloud/express-on-dotcloud/blob/master/app/views/welcome.jade#L1

If you are starting with Node and Express feel free to clone this demo/tutorial App:
https://github.com/dotcloud/express-on-dotcloud

You can fool with it localy and discover some nice features of Express 3, if you want to share your app it is all setup to be pushed to [dotCloud](http://dotcloud.com).

Comment: Thank you so much! As you can tell, I am new to Express, and as a result seem quite dumb.

Comment: Don't feel like it. Express 3 just came out and the doc is just not that great compare to the previous one. And most examples you will find will be Express 2. Enjoy this one it shall work fine. I've put lots of neat features from Express with lots of comments. And it pushes easily to dotCloud which is piratical :D